# BackgroundImage is resized about 130% bigger than oryginal *.png

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, aspose

I'm trying make a pdf file with use of aspose.pdf for .NET version 5.0.0.

My code looks like:

```
        var license = new License();
        license.SetLicense("path/My.lic");

        var document = new Pdf();
        document.Security = new Security();
        document.Security.IsAnnotationsModifyingAllowed = false;

        //Restrict contents modification
        document.Security.IsContentsModifyingAllowed = false;

        //Restrict copying the data
        document.Security.IsCopyingAllowed = false;

        //Allow to print the document
        document.Security.IsPrintingAllowed = true;

        //Restrict form filling
        document.Security.IsFormFillingAllowed = false;
        document.GraphInfo.Flatness = 1;

        Section mainSection = document.Sections.Add();
        //var signature = new Image(mainSection);
        //signature.ImageInfo.File = "path/MyBackgroundImage.png";
        //signature.ImageInfo.ImageFileType = ImageFileType.Png;


        mainSection.BackgroundImageFile = "path/MyBackgroundImage.png";
        mainSection.BackgroundImageType = ImageFileType.Png;
        mainSection.PageInfo.PageWidth = 1052*72*32;//PageSize.A4Width;
        mainSection.PageInfo.PageHeight = 744 * 72 * 32;//PageSize.A4Height;
        document.SetUnicode();
        document.Save("path/Name.pdf");
```

problem is that Image which should be pass as background image is resized even when I pass `PageWidth` and `PageHeight` values in exact points values(I found out that aspose gets size in points not in pixels. Conversion depends on dpi of picture which in my case is equal to 32 per inch so : `Points = Pixels * 72 * 32` for my case)

size of my picture is 1052 pixels width * 744 pixels with 32 dpi *.png extension;

What should I change in my code to make it work as it should?

If any further information needed please ask.

Thanks in advanced:)

Comment: How do you know your DPI ?  And it's an attribue of both your PDF and the PNG. They should probably match.

Comment: I check it in explorer properties of png file. Pdf file doesn't contain such value as dpi :(